# Create new data.table columns based on other columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` containing some state name abbreviations and county names. I want to get approx. coordinates from `ggplot2::map_data('county')` for each row.

I can do this sequentially with multiple lines of code using `:=` but I would like to make only one function call.

Below is what I've tried:

**Data:**

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

> dput(dt[1:20, .(state, county, prime_mover)])
structure(list(state = c("AZ", "AZ", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CT", 
"FL", "IN", "MA", "MA", "MA", "MN", "NJ", "NJ", "NJ", "NY", "NC", 
"SC", "TN", "TX"), county = c("Maricopa", "Maricopa", "Los Angeles", 
"Orange", "Los Angeles", "Fairfield", "Hillsborough", "Morgan", 
"Barnstable", "Nantucket", "Essex", "Dakota", "Cape May", "Salem", 
"Middlesex", "Kings", "Buncombe", "Anderson", "Shelby", "Tarrant"
), prime_mover = c("GT", "GT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "CT", "GT", 
"CT", "GT", "GT", "GT", "GT", "CT", "GT", "CT", "GT", "CT", "CT", 
"CT", "CT")), .Names = c("state", "county", "prime_mover"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

coord_data <- as.data.table(map_data('county'))
```

**CODE:**

```
getCoords <- function(state, county){
  prov <- state.name[grep(state, state.abb)]
  ck <- coord_data[region == tolower(prov) & subregion == tolower(county), 
                   .(lon = mean(long), lat = mean(lat))]
  return(list(unname(unlist(ck))))
}

# Testing getCoords
> getCoords('AZ', 'Maricopa')
[[1]]
[1] -111.88668   33.58126
```

**ERRORS:**

```
> dt[, c('lon', 'lat') := lapply(.SD, getCoords), .SDcols = c('state', 'county')]
Error in tolower(county) : argument "county" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning message:
In grep(state, state.abb) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I've seen the following answers but am not able to quite get what I'm doing wrong:

1. [Loop through data.table and create new columns basis some condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339027/loop-through-data-table-and-create-new-columns-basis-some-condition)
2. [R data.table create new columns with standard names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878098/r-data-table-create-new-columns-with-standard-names)
3. [Add new columns to a data.table containing many variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443658/add-new-columns-to-a-data-table-containing-many-variables)
4. [Add multiple columns to R data.table in one function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308754/add-multiple-columns-to-r-data-table-in-one-function-call)
5. [Assign multiple columns using := in data.table, by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680579/assign-multiple-columns-using-in-data-table-by-group)
6. [Dynamically create new columns in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258008/dynamically-create-new-columns-in-data-table)

I am able to achieve what I want by other means (multiple lines, `dplyr` or even base R) but I prefer to use the `data.table` approach for this.

Comment: `lapply` is for applying a function multiple times, once to each column. You can use `do.call(fun, .SD)` to pass multiple cols as separate arguments to a single function call (or maybe `do.call(fun, unname(.SD))` to pass by position).

Comment: or `dt[, c('lon', 'lat') := getCoords(state, county), by=1:NROW(dt)]`

Comment: @Frank Thanks! can you explain how/why that works?

Comment: @dww I don't get any errors but there are many warnings mostly to do with the size of what is returned by `getCoords`. The code chunk writes the first element of the output from `getCoords` to both `lon` and `lat`.

Comment: This works as far as I can see. `dt[,lon := getCoords(state, county)[[1]][1],by=1:NROW(dt)][, lat:=getCoords(state, county)[[1]][2],by=1:NROW(dt)]` Based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308946/5795592

Comment: The description in `?do.call` gives the intuition "`do.call` constructs and executes a function call from a name or a function and a list of arguments to be passed to it." So `do.call(f, list(x = 1, y = 3:4))` evaluates `f(x = 1, y = 3:4)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with two *update joins*:

```
library(data.table)
# aggregate coordinates
cols <- c("long", "lat")
agg_coord <- coord_data[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = cols, by = .(region, subregion)]
# coerce to data.table by reference
setDT(dt)[
  # 1st update join to append region/state.name
  .(state = state.abb, state.name = tolower(state.name)), 
  on = "state", region := state.name][
    # append subregion
    , subregion := tolower(county)][
      # 2nd update join to append coordinates
      agg_coord, on = .(region, subregion), (cols) := .(long, lat)][
        # remove helper columns
        , c("region", "subregion") := NULL]
# print updated dt
dt[]
```

> ```
>     state       county prime_mover       long      lat
>  1:    AZ     Maricopa          GT -111.88668 33.58126
>  2:    AZ     Maricopa          GT -111.88668 33.58126
>  3:    CA  Los Angeles          CT -118.29410 34.06683
>  4:    CA       Orange          CT -117.73632 33.69611
>  5:    CA  Los Angeles          CT -118.29410 34.06683
>  6:    CT    Fairfield          CT  -73.35118 41.29633
>  7:    FL Hillsborough          GT  -82.47527 27.87826
>  8:    IN       Morgan          CT  -86.49791 39.52721
>  9:    MA   Barnstable          GT  -70.21598 41.79520
> 10:    MA    Nantucket          GT  -70.05841 41.29880
> 11:    MA        Essex          GT  -70.98384 42.64042
> 12:    MN       Dakota          GT  -93.04962 44.70344
> 13:    NJ     Cape May          CT  -74.80790 39.15476
> 14:    NJ        Salem          GT  -75.36532 39.58720
> 15:    NJ    Middlesex          CT  -74.42345 40.45429
> 16:    NY        Kings          GT  -73.95052 40.64792
> 17:    NC     Buncombe          CT  -82.50883 35.62002
> 18:    SC     Anderson          CT  -82.61956 34.57094
> 19:    TN       Shelby          CT  -89.99297 35.22379
> 20:    TX      Tarrant          CT  -97.29396 32.79856
> ```